# Remove newlines between Authors, title and journal in bibliography using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, natbib

recently I had to change the layout of my document, and the new layout uses natbib. The issue that natbib is adding a line break between author's name, title and journal name.

I'm not changing any parameter or redefining anything in the document so I wonder where can be the problem.

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
\bibliography{sample}
```

I want to have each entry in one line (not all the bibliography in one line):
example:

> Yuanhang Wang, Chao Deng, Jun Wu, Yingchun Wang, and Yao Xiong. A corrective maintenance scheme for engineering equipment. Engineering Failure Analysis, 36:269–283, 2014.

> Richard C Dorf and Robert H Bishop. Modern control systems. Pearson, 2011.

and not:

> Yuanhang Wang, Chao Deng, Jun Wu, Yingchun Wang, and Yao Xiong.
> A corrective maintenance scheme for engineering equipment.
> Engineering Failure Analysis, 36:269–283, 2014.

> Richard C Dorf and Robert H Bishop.
> Modern control systems.
> Pearson, 2011.

But this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Update:
This is the cls file the journal provided me: [IWCOMP.cls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fkBTMrrqZxS4_o3UxjtORrOUnSm9iF1S/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `natbib` is primarily a citation management package. The formatting of bibliographic entries is *not* governed by `natbib`, but by the bibliography style that's in use. Curiously, the particular output you're showing in the screenshot does not look *anything* like what's generally known to be produced by the `unsrtnat` style. Do you maybe have more than one `\bibliographystyle` instruction in your document?

Comment: Just on the off chance that the version of the `unsrtnat.bst` file that's on your system somehow got corrupted, please perform the following diagnostic check: Download the file `https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/unsrtnat.bst` from the CTAN, copy it to the directory that contains your main tex file (and `sample.bib` too, presumably), and perform a full recompilation cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. Does the odd-ball formatting of the bibliographic entries persist?

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your anser, I tried using the bst files from ctan (and did a full recompilation) but unfortunately it did not change. I updated the question with the cls file I'm using, probably it can provide us more info about the issue.

Comment: Update: Removing the openbib option in the cls file solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the output with the `openbib` option.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wang-et-al2014,
  author={{Yuanhang Wang} and {Chao Deng} and {Jun Wu} and {Yingchun Wang} and {Yao Xiong}},
  title={A corrective maintenance scheme for engineering equipment},
  journal={Engineering Failure Analysis},
  volume={36},
  pages={269–283},
  year=2014,
}
@book{dorf-bishop2011,
  author={Richard C. Dorf and Robert H. Bishop},
  title={Modern control systems},
  publisher={Pearson},
  year=2011,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[openbib]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{wang-et-al2014}, \cite{dorf-bishop2011}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Check that your document class doesn't set the option.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue, I uploaded the cls file I'm using, It was setting somewhere openbib. removing it solved the problem.